# abrir una página con un button pero sin abrir en otra pestaña

Tags: html5

quiero con un button abrir una página, pero que no se abra en otra pestaña sino que se abra en la misma y no lo consigo.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btnterapia" onClick="parent.open('http://localhost/adela/contacto/')">PIDA CITA</button>   

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btnterapia" onClick="window.open('http://localhost/adela/contacto/')">PIDA CITA</button>
```

Que tengo que poner en onclick=".........('http....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas si quieres abrir otra página en ésta misma página podrías usar javascript siempre que esté habilitado.

Te quedaría algo así:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btnterapia" onclick="location.href='http://localhost/adela/contacto/';">PIDA CITA</button>
```

Si estas `class` aplican el CSS mismo en todos los elementos podrías usar una etiqueta simple tipo `<a href></a>` y poner las `class` para que visualmente se comporte como un `button`:

```
 <a class="btn btn-success btnterapia" href="http://localhost/adela/contacto/" >PIDA CITA</a>
```

Entiendo que cualquiera de éstos dos métodos puede y debería funcionar-te. :)

[html](/questions/tagged/html)[js](/questions/tagged/js)[css](/questions/tagged/css)

Answer (score 2):

Deberías realizarlo mejor con el elemento `<a>` pero con [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/open) puedes conseguirlo también:

```
<button onclick="window.open('http://localhost/adela/contacto/', '_self')">Click me</button>
```

cual le pasas el  target `_self` para abrirlo en la misma ventana.

Comment: Voté negativo sin querer, creo que al hacer scroll con el móvil debí darle a la flecha. No puedo rectificar si no se edita, @aldanux si editas la respuesta te quito el negativo

Comment: Ok, arreglado. Lo siento, fue un error